# 60 amp breaker installation

Tags: electrical

Are the two wires going into a 60 amp breaker interchangeable?  I am changing out breakers and the wires I will be taking out seem to be cut to fit differently than the current installation.

Comment: Per your other question, you should confirm that the wiring will support a 60A breaker. A photo of both breakers would help answer this question. Are you sure the breaker is compatible with your service panel?

Answer (score 2):

If it's a 60 ampere double pole breaker, in a 120/240V single split-phase panel.  Then yes, the two ungrounded (hot) conductors can be connected to either leg. As long as they are on separate legs, the color of the insulation makes no difference (as long as it's not green, and if it's white it is properly marked).